# I'm having difficulty translating colloquial Spanish use of 'vah'

Tags: coloquialismos, conjugación, español-neutral

I am translating a letter from Spanish to English, and the first sentence is *España vah, bien*', which I am having difficulty working out.
I assume this is a colloquial use of '*vah*', but I am unsure how to translate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Vah* is not an existing word in Spanish.

---

In written Spanish, sometimes we use the mute letter "h" to mimic an aspirated sound to denote a long or stretched syllable. The proof is in the comma which indicates a short pause as if the interlocutor were thinking about the right next word.

The real phrase is "España va bien" (Spain goes well), originally pronounced by ex-president *José María Aznar* in reference to the country's economic advances during his government.

From there arose various meanings, most of them in a satirical way.

The phrase "España vah, bien" could well be translated as "Spain goes..., well" where the three dots indicate the hesitant pause.

---

Another feasible option is a misspelling:

> "España bah! Bien"

- Spain bah! Good.

---

Comment: It is probably wordplay between *España va bien* and *bah*.